# Input a list of numbers and and replace each element in the list with its factorial(use factorial() from math module)

Tags: list, python-module

Hey I'm new to lists and modules can you show me how to do this. I actually tried this code but it seems to be giving me a wrong answer

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

fact = 1
for i in l:
for number in range(1,i+1):
fact=fact*number
print ("Factorial of", i, "is", fact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for number in l:
    fact = factorial(number)
    print("Facotrial of ",number," is",fact)
```

Here is a working example.

You can use the balise code to better show your code, I have trouble to read it so I can't really comment on what you did wrong

Comment: How to do it without def function

Comment: You have to add this line at the beginning of the code: import math

Then you get a factorial by using math.factorial(your_number)